# How to get coordinates of element inside list

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a question...

I have `NSCollectionView` with many `NSBox` as list elements. Inside each `NSBox` i have button...

I have action for that button which shoud return coordinates of each `NSBox` relative do `NSCollectionView`, but it dosen't, it returns always the same coordinate... i use `[sender frame]`

`- (IBAction)showInformationWindow:(id)sender { ... [sender frame] ...}`

`NSBox` and `NSCollectionView` are separete Nib's.

**QUESTION**

How to get coordinates of element inside list using action inside that element.

I hope that i didn't mess to much with my explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `self`...

inside NSBox action:

```
- (IBAction)showInformationWindow:(id)sender {
   ...    
   NSRect coordinates = [self frame];
   ...
}
```